# Start solr-DataImport via linux shell (cron)?

Tags: shell, solr, dataimporthandler

Currently im running solr 3.1 on a tomcat 6 on a ubuntu 10.04 machine.
Everything works, i can start indexing from my mysql-database via
http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
which returns some data about the indexing process.

Now i want to trigger a redindex/update via cron, so it would be nice to do it via "java -jar ..." and not cia curl. At best the program would run as long as the reindex/update takes and return the stats if finished, so my shell script will wait for the update to finish.
Is this archivable ?

Answer (score 4):

Well you can achieve that by using a simple script that has following steps

1. GET    http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
2. while True

   2.1     GET http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=status INTO status.xml

   2.2     PARSE status.xml to check for indexing completed

   2.3     IF completed break

   2.4     ELSE SLEEP 1